# Center aligning chapters

Tags: sectioning, horizontal-alignment, chapters, titlesec

I'm using the following to center align chapters. Heres the code

```
 \newcommand{\cchapter}[1]{\chapter[#1]{\centering #1}}
```

And using `\cchapter` to format chapters. But the chapter heading for eg. "Chapter 1" is not getting center aligned. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I recommend to use the [`titlesec`](http://ctan.org/pkg/titlesec) package. Here's an example:

```
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\normalfont\huge\bfseries\centering}
  {\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter}{20pt}{\Huge}
```

This is similar to the standard chapter plus `\centering`.

I prefer sans serif headings, because I think bold headings with serifs are too heavy. Hoewver, serifs are great for body text. Recently I used this:

```
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\normalfont\sffamily\Large\bfseries\centering}
  {\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter}{0pt}{\Huge}
\titleformat{\section}
  {\normalfont\sffamily\large\bfseries\centering}
  {\thesection}{1em}{}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{30pt}{20pt}
```

To get:

[image]

Also because of the lighter appearance of those bold headings, KOMA-Script classes use sans-serif headings by default.

Comment: That was perfect. Thanks. Unfortunately I can't upvote yet