# Fancy chapter head with fancyhdr?

Tags: fancyhdr

I use `fancyhdr' to make chapter title for my thesis,

`\usepackage{fancyhdr}`

`\usepackage[Lenny]{fncychap}`

Any idea of other fancy headings using the same package? I don't want to change 'fancyhdr' as that will amount to me changing a lot in my template. Martin's submission (link below) looks really great...with title **'Chapter 3'**. Is it possible to use `fancyhdr` to do same?

[Fancy Chapter Headings](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14310/fancy-chapter-headings)

Comment: **fancyhdr** has nothing to do with the chapter headings; it controls the typesetting of page header and footer. Usually I advise against using **fncychap**, but that's personal opinion.

Comment: @egreg: Oh thanks for pointing that out! Yes, `fncychap` isn't great...but does it also have any repercussion or against standard thesis typesetting? Do you have suggestion to replace `fncyhchap`?

Comment: The styles provided by **fncychap** go, in my opinion, from ugly to preposterously horrible ("Lenny" falls into the last category, I'm afraid). The package **titlesec** has some more pleasant examples.

Comment: @egreg : you've just wowed me! Thank you! I use the `titlesec package` as below, so simple and great!`\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt, twoside]{Thesis}  % `
`\graphicspath{{Figures/}}  % `
`\usepackage[outermarks]{titlesec}`
`\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\arabic{chapter}}`
`\titleformat{\chapter}[display]`
`{\bfseries\LARGE}`
`{\filleft\MakeUppercase{\chaptertitlename} \Huge\thechapter}
{4ex}`
`{\titlerule`
`\vspace{.5ex}%`
`\filright}`
`[\vspace{2ex}%`
`\titlerule]`
`\begin{doc}`

blac blac blac

`\end{document}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**fancyhdr** has nothing to do with the chapter headings; it controls the typesetting of page header and footer.

In order to change the chapter headers, a good source of examples is the package **titlesec**

For example:

```
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\bfseries\LARGE}
  {\filleft\MakeUppercase{\chaptertitlename}\quad\Huge\thechapter}
  {4ex}
  {\titlerule\vspace{1ex}\filright}
  [\vspace{1ex}\titlerule]
```

(slightly modified from your comment).