# Fancy Chapter Headings - onesided version?

Tags: sectioning

I would like to create titles of my single sided thesis like the one given in books (and can be seen in the following link), I tried to change the code given by Martin in the following link, but didn't get the desired output

[Fancy Chapter Headings](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14310/fancy-chapter-headings)

This is Martin's code:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{graphics}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\normalfont\Large\raggedleft}
  {\MakeUppercase{\chaptertitlename}%
    \rlap{ \resizebox{!}{1.5cm}{\thechapter} \rule{5cm}{1.5cm}}}
  {10pt}{\Huge}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{30pt}{20pt}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\setcounter{chapter}{2}
\begin{document}

\chapter{Implementation}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

Here is what it currently looks like:

[image]

I am trying to change the printed output from right to left side, how should i modify the code? I just want to write the black box then chapter number, ENTER then Chapter Name in Centre.

Comment: Hard to tell what the problem might be with such little information. Which document class do you use? Can you show us a minimal complete document with your current attempt?

Comment: Thanks for quick response, \documentclass{book}
\usepackage{graphics}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\normalfont\Large\raggedleft}
  {\MakeUppercase{\chaptertitlename}%
    \rlap{ \resizebox{!}{1.5cm}{\thechapter} \rule{5cm}{1.5cm}}}
  {10pt}{\Huge}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{30pt}{20pt}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\setcounter{chapter}{2}
\begin{document}

\chapter{Implementation}
\lipsum
\end{document}

Comment: Please add the code to your answer, not in a comment. What exactly seems to be the problem with that code?

Comment: sorry for such ridiculous outout, i am new here, so please apolo...

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look on [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: @user31844 No need to apologize :-) In no time you'll get used to the way things work here.

Comment: Thanks :) I am trying to change the printed output from right to left side, how should i modify the code?

Comment: How should the information be displayed? Chapter label (the word "Chapter"), then chapter number; in a new line the chapter title? The number outside the margin?

Comment: If you take a look at the link in question, there you can see the Chapter heading and Chapter name, I want all the things like that, but just want to write all that things on left side instead of right side, the black box then chapter number, ENTER then Chapter Name in Centre

Comment: OK. Please add all this information as an edit to your question so other people can find it easily.

Comment: ok I have added the info... to my capacity of english

Comment: I've taken the liberty of editing your question to incorporate the information in your comments. I also changed the title to make it more descriptive.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here you go.

```
\documentclass[oneside]{book}
\usepackage{graphics}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\normalfont\Large\raggedright}
  {\hspace{0cm}\llap{%
    \rule{5cm}{1.5cm}\hspace{0.2cm}\resizebox{!}{1.5cm}{\thechapter}\hspace{0.2cm}}%
    \MakeUppercase{\chaptertitlename}}
  {10pt}{\Huge}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{30pt}{20pt}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\setcounter{chapter}{2}
\begin{document}

\chapter{Implementation}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Can i change the colour of box from dark black to light grey?