# Clarification on old Comment

Tags: sectioning, chapters

This post has a very nice answer from Martin Scharrer

[Fancy Chapter Headings](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14310/fancy-chapter-headings?rq=1)

The OP responds saying that he added a ~ after chapter and number for a nicer layout.
What does he mean?

Comment: I think he means something like `\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\normalfont\Large\raggedleft}
  {\MakeUppercase{\chaptertitlename~}%
    \rlap{ \resizebox{!}{1.5cm}{\thechapter~} \rule{5cm}{1.5cm}}}
  {10pt}{\Huge}`  Note the two added `~` and what they do to the original output.  The word "chapter" is shifted slightly left, and the black bar is offset further right.

Comment: Thanks that's it! Think I preferred it without the "~" though

Comment: with...without.  That's the beauty of LaTeX.  At the flick of the wrist, you can have your cake and eat it too.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes sounds like an answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Martin's answer at [Fancy Chapter Headings](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14310/fancy-chapter-headings?rq=1) produced the following output (zoomed):

[image]

The comment by the OP discussed taking Martin's definition of `\titleformat`:

```
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\normalfont\Large\raggedleft}
  {\MakeUppercase{\chaptertitlename}%
    \rlap{ \resizebox{!}{1.5cm}{\thechapter} \rule{5cm}{1.5cm}}}
  {10pt}{\Huge}
```

and adding two spaces `~`, one after `\chaptertitlename` and the other after `\thechapter` as follows:

```
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\normalfont\Large\raggedleft}
  {\MakeUppercase{\chaptertitlename~}%
    \rlap{ \resizebox{!}{1.5cm}{\thechapter~} \rule{5cm}{1.5cm}}}
  {10pt}{\Huge}
```

The net effect would be to push the word "CHAPTER" one space to the left (since it is a right-aligned field), and to add a space after the chapter number (in this case "3") which effectively offsets the black bar to the right.  The result is:

[image]

As in many things, preference plays a large role...unless your editor tells you otherwise ;^)